# How to convert numpy.recarray to numpy.array?

Tags: python, numpy

What's the best way to convert numpy's `recarray` to a normal array?

i could do a `.tolist()` first and then do an `array()` again, but that seems somewhat inefficient..

Example:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.recarray((2,), dtype=[('x', int), ('y', float), ('z', int)])

>>> a
  rec.array([(30408891, 9.2944097561804909e-296, 30261980),
   (44512448, 4.5273310988985789e-300, 29979040)], 
  dtype=[('x', '<i4'), ('y', '<f8'), ('z', '<i4')])

>>> np.array(a.tolist())
   array([[  3.04088910e+007,   9.29440976e-296,   3.02619800e+007],
   [  4.45124480e+007,   4.52733110e-300,   2.99790400e+007]])
```

Comment: You aren't getting any answers because we don't understand your question.  Try to reword your question, and include any relevant code.

Comment: To the down-voters I ask that you be a little more patient.  This is a person who hasn't asked questions here before and hasn't had much time to revise the question.  If the question stays in this poor form for too long, by all means down-vote it.

Comment: ok sorry guys, added an example. is this clearer?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

By "normal array" I take it you mean a NumPy array of homogeneous dtype. Given a recarray, such as:

```
>>> a = np.array([(0, 1, 2),
              (3, 4, 5)],[('x', int), ('y', float), ('z', int)]).view(np.recarray)
rec.array([(0, 1.0, 2), (3, 4.0, 5)], 
      dtype=[('x', '<i4'), ('y', '<f8'), ('z', '<i4')])
```

we must first make each column have the same dtype. We can then convert it to a "normal array" by viewing the data by the same dtype:

```
>>> a.astype([('x', '<f8'), ('y', '<f8'), ('z', '<f8')]).view('<f8')
array([ 0.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.])
```

---

[astype](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.astype.html) returns a new numpy array. So the above requires additional memory in an amount proportional to the size of `a`. Each row of `a` requires 4+8+4=16 bytes, while `a.astype(...)` requires 8*3=24 bytes. Calling [view](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.view.html) requires no new memory, since `view` just changes how the underlying data is interpreted.

`a.tolist()` returns a new Python list. Each Python number is an object which requires more bytes than its equivalent representation in a numpy array. So `a.tolist()` requires more memory than `a.astype(...)`.

Calling `a.astype(...).view(...)` is also faster than `np.array(a.tolist())`:

```
In [8]: a = np.array(zip(*[iter(xrange(300))]*3),[('x', int), ('y', float), ('z', int)]).view(np.recarray)

In [9]: %timeit a.astype([('x', '<f8'), ('y', '<f8'), ('z', '<f8')]).view('<f8')
10000 loops, best of 3: 165 us per loop

In [10]: %timeit np.array(a.tolist())
1000 loops, best of 3: 683 us per loop
```

Comment: You may need to ensure that the array is contiguous: np.ascontiguousarray(a, [('x', '<f8'), ('y', '<f8'), ('z', '<f8')]).view('<f8'), see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29629157/how-to-convert-a-subset-of-numpy-recarray-to-continuous-array?lq=1

Answer (score 3):

Here is a relatively clean solution using `pandas`:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> a = np.recarray((2,), dtype=[('x', int), ('y', float), ('z', int)])
>>> arr = pd.DataFrame(a).to_numpy()
>>> arr
array([[9.38925058e+013, 0.00000000e+000, 1.40380704e+014],
       [1.40380704e+014, 6.93572751e-310, 1.40380484e+014]])
>>> arr.shape
(2, 3)
>>> arr.dtype
dtype('float64')
```

First the data from the `recarray` are loaded into a `pd.DataFrame`, then the data are exported using the `DataFrame.to_numpy` method. As we can see, this method call has automatically converted all of the data to type `float64`.