# Using numpy fromfile on binary file returns 1 dimension ndarray

Tags: python, numpy

I'm using numpy's fromfile function to read data from a binary file. The file contains a sequence of values (3 * float32, 3 * int8, 3 * float32) which I want to extract into a numpy ndarray with (rows, 9) shape.

```
with open('file/path', 'rb') as my_file:
    my_dtype = np.dtype('>f4, >f4, >f4, >i1, >i1, >i1, >f4, >f4, >f4' )
    my_array = np.fromfile( my_file, dtype = my_dtype )

    print(my_array.shape)
    print(type(my_array[0]))
    print(my_array[0])
```

And this returns:

```
(38475732,)
<type 'numpy.void'>
(-775.0602416992188, -71.0, -242.5240020751953, 39, 39, 39, 5.0, 2753.0, 15328.0)
```

1. How can I get a 2 dimensional ndarray with shape (38475732, 9,)?
2. Why the returned tuple is of type 'numpy.void'?

**Redefining question:**

If all the values that I want to read from the file were, for example, 4 byte floats I would use np.dtype('9>f4') and I would get what I need. But, as my binary file contains different types, is there a way of casting all the values into 32bit floats?

PS: I can do this using 'struct' to parse the binary file into a list and converting this list into an ndarray afterwards, but this method is much slower than using np.fromfile

**Solution:**

Thanks Hpaulj for your answer! What I did in my code was to add the following line to do the conversion from the recarray returned by the numpy fromfile function to the expected ndarray:

```
my_array = my_array.astype('f4, f4, f4, f4, f4, f4, f4, f4, f4').view(dtype='f4').reshape(my_array.shape[0], 9)
```

Which returns a (38475732, 9) ndarray

Cheers!

Comment: what's the value of sys.byteorder?

Comment: it returns 'little' but I don't see why is this important...

Comment: You are using '>' which is for big endian. Did you try using little ending data type which is '<'?

Comment: The values I get inside the tuple are correct. The problem is rather in defining a dtype expression which maps into a 2d ndarray

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is `my_array[[0]]`?  `my_array` is a 1d array of records defined by `my_dtype`.

`my_array[0]` is one of those records, a tuple.  Notice that some entries are float, some integers.  If it was a row of a 2d array, all entries would be of the same type (e.g. float).

To convert it to a 2d array of floats, you might try:

```
np.array(my_array.tolist())
```

Another way is to convert all the fields to the same type, and reshape it.  Something along this line (tested on a different recarray):

```
x = array([(1.0, 2), (3.0, 4)], dtype=[('x', '<f8'), ('y', '<i4')])
x.astype([('x', '<f8'), ('y', '<f8')]).view(dtype='f8').reshape(2,2)
```

See also: [How to convert numpy.recarray to numpy.array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7842157/how-to-convert-numpy-recarray-to-numpy-array)

Comment: my_array[[0]] = [(-775.0602416992188, -71.0, -242.5240020751953, 39, 39, 39, 5.0, 2753.0, 15328.0)]

Answer (score 0):

Since you require your array to contain different datatypese, you get a [structured array](http://wiki.scipy.org/Cookbook/Recarray), where each element is a record. You can access fields with

```
>>> my_array.dtype.names
('f0', 'f1', 'f2', 'f3', 'f4', 'f5', 'f6', 'f7', 'f8')
>>> my_array[0]['f1']
-71.0
>>> my_array['f1']
array([-71.], dtype=float32)
```

A basic `ndarray` contains elements of same type, if you need a ndarray with shape (38475732, 9,), you have to convert your array to, say, floats. See link above.

Can't say exactly why (didn't use structured arrays much), but reason for `numpy.void` is that your custom type, known to array, is not broadcasted to records. But what would be type of subrecord?

```
>>> arr[['f0','f1']][0]
(-775.0602416992188, -71.0)
```